# I want to get a quarter value in NSDateComponents class

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I want to get a quarter value from specified date. (*date variable)

So. I have made following code and run.
but, quarter value is zero.

Why quarter value is zero?
where's problem?

Please advice from advanced man.

```
NSDateComponents *comp1 = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comp1 setYear:2012];
[comp1 setMonth:6];
[comp1 setDay:1];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comp1];  <== want to get a quarter value.

unsigned int unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSQuarterCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *comp2 = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:date];

NSLog(@"year :       %5d",[comp2 year]);
NSLog(@"quarter :    %5d",[comp2 quarter]);
NSLog(@"month :      %5d",[comp2 month]);
NSLog(@"weekofYear : %5d",[comp2 weekOfYear]);
NSLog(@"day :        %5d",[comp2 day]);
```

Result:

```
2012-07-24 03:44:14.776 dateTest[1228:1307] year :        2012
2012-07-24 03:44:14.776 dateTest[1228:1307] quarter :        0
2012-07-24 03:44:14.777 dateTest[1228:1307] month :          6
2012-07-24 03:44:14.777 dateTest[1228:1307] weekofYear :    22
2012-07-24 03:44:14.778 dateTest[1228:1307] day :            1
```

Comment: NSLog(@"quarter :    %5d",(0 == [comp2 quarter])?([comp2 month]-1)/3+1:[comp2 quarter]);

Comment: Hard to believe such an old bug still occurring (Swift 3.1)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that there is an issue with the NSQuarterCalendarUnit being ignored (haven't verified, but did see a bug reported).  Anyway, it is simple enough to get around... Just use the NSDateFormatter class.

```
// After your NSDate *date, add...
NSDateFormatter *quarterOnly = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[quarterOnly setDateFormat:@"Q"];

int quarter = [[quarterOnly stringFromDate:date] intValue];

// Then change the quarter NSLog too
NSLog(@"quarter :    %5d", quarter);
```

Should work fine...

Comment: above code well work. I wonder the reason. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Dec 16 2014

How about simply:

([comp2 month]-1)/3+1;

Comment: That assumes the Gregorian calendar.