# iOS and Objective-C: Repeating an event every quarter

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, foundation

I need to have an event repeat every "quarter" (which I assume means moving up 3 months approximately). So I could expect this to move the date (but it doesn't):

```
    NSDateComponents *component = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init]; // quarter
    component.quarter = 1;

    self.todoStartDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents: component toDate:self.todoStartDate options: 0];
```

Is there anything wrong with adding a "quarter" to a date? It works fine when adding a day or a week, but not with a "quarter".

Comment: Perhaps alternatively you could simply use the first day of four different months, e.g. January, April, July, and October (depends on whether you are specifically using Gregorian calendar etc)

Comment: Thanks. That's the thing: I don't want to make the assumption for which calendar the user is setup with. I'd rather let the foundation class handle this calculation. But it doesn't seem to do this, and I can't find any more documentation on it.

Answer (score 0):

(I wish I could add this as a formatted comment on applefreak's answer, which is a pretty good one. But SO doesn't allow markup in comments.)

[Apple's documentation for NSCalendar](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html) says:

> Some calendars represented by this API may have to map their basic
>   unit concepts into year/month/week/day/… nomenclature. For example, a
>   calendar composed of 4 quarters in a year instead of 12 months uses
>   the month unit to represent quarters.

Now, this could be a lot clearer, but I *think* what Apple is saying is that normal calendars don't have "quarters" at all; they only have years, months (12 of them), and days. But you can subclass `NSCalendar` (or create a new instance of `NSCalendar`?) so that the year has only 4 months, and then call those months "quarters", and for the benefit of such subclasses Apple has pre-defined the `quarter` property. This is horribly confusing; I bet there's a good story behind Apple's WTFery here.

Anyway, I agree with applefreak that you should be dealing in year/month/day dates anyway, not mucking around with mythical "quarters." After all, what would it even *mean* to "add", let's say, two quarters to March 31, given that Q3 is shorter than Q1? (And would the answer depend on whether this was a leap year?)

If what you really want is "an event recurring every year on January 1, April 1, July 1, and October 1," then you should write *that*. Don't even bother with "adding three months", which has the same problems as "adding one quarter".

BTW, other people here have noticed the `quarter` WTF as well. For example: [I want to get a quarter value in NSDateComponents class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618784/i-want-to-get-a-quarter-value-in-nsdatecomponents-class)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, don't know why the quarter doesn't work, so workaround by replacing quarter by month * 3. The following demonstrates how to get three quarters backward:

```
        NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        NSCalendar *theCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"QQQ yyyy";
        NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

        for (int i = -2; i <= 0; i++) {
            //dayComponent.quarter = i;
            dayComponent.month = i*3;

            NSDate *date = [theCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:currentDate options:0];

            NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

            NSLog(@"date = %@", dateString);
        }
```

I hope all this helps.