# dateByAddingComponents:dateRange toDate:firstDate options:0 is always returning current quarter

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I am using

```
- (NSDate *)dateByAddingComponents:(NSDateComponents *)comps toDate:(NSDate *)date options:(NSCalendarOptions)opts
```

to calculate a new date, like below:

```
NSDateComponents *quaterComps = [NSDateComponents new];
quaterComps.quarter = 1;

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDate *nextDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:quaterComps toDate:firstDate options:0];
```

When firstDate is 2013-12-31 16:00:00 +0000,

Above API keeps returning the same result, not the next quarter date

Comment: please go with this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699706/ios-and-objective-c-repeating-an-event-every-quarter

Answer (score -1):

** current date and next date **

```
 NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *futureTime = [currentDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*72];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    [calendar setTimeZone:timeZone];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:futureTime];
    if ([components hour] >= 19) { // make it the next day
        [components setDay:[components day] + 1 ];
    }
    [components setHour:8];
    [components setMinute:00];
    NSDate *alertTime = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

Comment: could you explain what your code does? I want get a date with its quarter + 1, but I don't see your code can do that.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *comp = [NSDateComponents new];
comp.weekOfYear = 3;
NSDate *date1 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:comp toDate:date options:0];
NSLog(@"date:  %@", date);
NSLog(@"date1: %@", date1)
```

Comment: Stop flooding answers... I know weekOfYear, but what I am asking is the quarter behaviour. I got strange behaviour for quarter, but others are good