# iphone UILocalNotification with 3 months as repeat interval

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

I need to set a uilocalnotification which first triggers 3 months from now and repeat every 3 months interval after that.

I set the fire date as 3 months from now, and its coming if I change the iPhone date to 3 moths advance.

But after that how to set the repeat interval to 3 months. like suppose jan 3rd, then april 3rd, then july 3rd etc..

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried it myself, but from the documentation I assume that

```
notification.repeatInterval = NSQuarterCalendarUnit;
```

does what you want.

**UPDATE:** I have now tested this and, as user1001011 reported, is does not work. But there seem also to be other problems with `NSQuarterCalendarUnit`, see for example

- [I want to get a quarter value in NSDateComponents class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618784/i-want-to-get-a-quarter-value-in-nsdatecomponents-class)
- http://openradar.appspot.com/9270112

So, unfortunately, the answer seems to be: It cannot be done.

Comment: @user1001011: See my updated answer. Unfortunately, I do not know a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this property of UILocalNotification:

```
    UILocalNotification *alarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    alarm.fireDate = date;
    alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    alarm.alertBody = msg;
    alarm.alertAction = @"Show";

    alarm.repeatInterval = NSMonthCalendarUnit*3;

    alarm.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    alarm.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    [app scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];
    [alarm release];
```

I Hope it's helpful to you.

Comment: `repeatInterval` must be one of the `NSCalenderUnit` values. You cannot multiply these values to get a new interval.