# components:NSQuarterCalendarUnit gives the total quarters between 2 dates?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

```
       NSDateComponents *result = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSQuarterCalendarUnit fromDate:start toDate:end options:0];

      NSInteger numberOfQuaters = [result quarter];
```

why this code will return always 0 ?

That shouldn't give me the number of quarters between NSDate start and NSDate end ?

For example if start is 1 jan 2012 and end is 3 jun 2013 i should have numberOfQuarters = 6

Comment: This seems to be an Apple bug, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618784/i-want-to-get-a-quarter-value-in-nsdatecomponents-class or http://openradar.appspot.com/9270112

Comment: Also that is affected by bug ? NSCalendarUnit unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSQuarterCalendarUnit;

Comment: Do you still need help with this, or is the issue solved in the meantime?

Comment: While there's still this odd bug i've found the solution i'm going to post, here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this solution while the odd Apple's bug is still there:

> numberOfQuarters = (4 - startQuarter) + ((endYear -1  - startYear) * 4) + endQuarter;