# Getting the first date of current quarter

Tags: ios, nsdate, nscalendar

I'm trying to get the first and the last date of current quarter, i'm using it:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitQuarter | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];

components.quarter = 1;

funStartDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents: components];
NSLog(@"First day of quater: %@", funStartDate);

[components setQuarter:[components quarter]+1];

funEndDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents: components];
NSLog(@"Last day of quater: %@", [funEndDate descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]);
```

But in both console print I see today's date. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Since you have day, month, and year in your components, quarter is considered superfluous (and inconsistent) and is ignored. (I'd just add 3 to month -- and of course "wrap" at the end of the year.)  (Or, probably better, use dateByAddingCompoonents.)

Comment: Log the value of `quarter`. Is this feature even working? No, it isn't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618784/i-want-to-get-a-quarter-value-in-nsdatecomponents-class So abandon all hope of getting your code to work that way.

Comment: Actually, @HotLicks, there is no need to "wrap" the year. Adding 3 to the months component will work correctly. Date components _is_ (are) the correct way to do calendar arithmetic.

Answer (score 8):

UPDATED: I've found that Apple's bug with quarter unit is still there in iOS 7.1, so avoid using this unit in your date components.

Here I got working solution for you:

first day of a quarter:

```
    NSDate *date = <whatever>;
    NSCalendar *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *startOfQuarter;
    [currentCalendar rangeOfUnit: NSQuarterCalendarUnit
                       startDate: &startOfQuarter
                        interval: NULL
                         forDate: date];
    NSLog(@"quarter starts at %@", startOfQuarter);
```

last day of a quarter:

```
    NSDateComponents* comps = [currentCalendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay)
                                                 fromDate:date];
    NSUInteger quartalNum = (comps.month - 1) / 3 + 1;
    NSUInteger lastQuartalMonthNum = quartalNum * 3;
    NSUInteger nextQuartalFirstMonth = lastQuartalMonthNum + 1
    [comps setMonth: nextQuartalFirstMonth];
    [comps setDay: 0]; // with 0 day we get last day of previous month

    NSLog(@"quarter ends at %@",  [currentCalendar dateFromComponents: comps]);
```

Comment: It's not working I have an error: Value of type Calendar has no member rangeOfUnit

Comment: @AdamSmaka The Swift 3 equivalent is `dateInterval(of:  start: interval: for:)`

Answer (score 8):

Swift 3.1. Quarter component still not working. Workaround:

```
extension Date {
    public var startOfQuarter: Date {
        let startOfMonth = Calendar.current.date(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: self)))!

        var components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day, .year], from: startOfMonth)

        let newMonth: Int
        switch components.month! {
        case 1,2,3: newMonth = 1
        case 4,5,6: newMonth = 4
        case 7,8,9: newMonth = 7
        case 10,11,12: newMonth = 10
        default: newMonth = 1
        }
        components.month = newMonth
        return Calendar.current.date(from: components)!
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Date().startOfQuarter
```