# How to get valid quarter count instead of NSDateComponents.quarter is returning 0

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, nsdatecomponents

`NSDateComponents.quarter` is returning 0 instead of valid quarter count.

I googled and it is said it is a bug for apple found in 2012. However, now it is 2015 and iOS 8.3, bug still exists.

What I need is the quarter count from `firstDate` to `lastDate`

for example:

```
unitFlags = NSQuarterCalendarUnit;

(lldb) po firstDate
2009-12-31 16:00:00 +0000

(lldb) po lastDate
2013-09-30 16:00:00 +0000

(lldb) po [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:firstDate toDate:lastDate options:0];
<NSDateComponents: 0x170158b50>
    Quarter: 0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to get a quarter value in NSDateComponents class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618784/i-want-to-get-a-quarter-value-in-nsdatecomponents-class)

Comment: The root cause is same, but my question is not. I need the quarter count from `firstDate` to `lastDate`