# What does the Quarter Component in Calender.Component do? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, date

I am trying to use yearly quarters in my iOS application but have found that the `.quarter` component does nothing.  There is also no documentation I could find on it.

Calling `print(Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .quarter, value: 1, to: Date()))` just prints the current date.  I would have expected it to add 3 months on to it?

Comment: The quarter component seems to be buggy, here is another report: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618784/i-want-to-get-a-quarter-value-in-nsdatecomponents-class.

Comment: @MartinR Wow, that was 4 years ago. You would think they would have noticed and perhaps fixed it by now...

Comment: From the docs: `The quarter unit is largely unimplemented, and is not recommended for use.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd think that wouldn't you — but no, it appears something is broken.

A quick test in a Playground shows it all works until you use a `.quarter`:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

let result = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .quarter, value: 1, to: Date())

print (result)

let calendar1 = Calendar.current
let now1 = Date()
let newDate1 = calendar1.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 1, to: now1)
let newDate2 = calendar1.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 1, to: now1)
let newDate3 = calendar1.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: now1)
let newDate4 = calendar1.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: now1)
let newDate5 = calendar1.date(byAdding: .month, value: 3, to: now1)
let newDate6 = calendar1.date(byAdding: .quarter, value: 1, to: now1)
```

Results in:

```
"Sep 27, 2016, 3:30 PM"

"Optional(2016-09-27 05:30:03 +0000)\n"

gregorian (current)
"Sep 27, 2016, 3:30 PM"
"Sep 27, 2016, 3:31 PM"
"Sep 27, 2016, 4:30 PM"
"Sep 28, 2016, 3:30 PM"
"Oct 27, 2016, 3:30 PM"
"Dec 27, 2016, 3:30 PM"
"Sep 27, 2016, 3:30 PM"
```

It looks like as it stands in Xcode  8.0 (8A218a) you will have use months and a value of `3` as shown in the `newDate5` line above.

Comment: That is unfortunate. Makes my code for calculating future quarterly bill dates from a start date a lot more complex than it should be...

Comment: same issue here, everything works except adding .quarters, temp workaround: using 3 .month